# Smoothly slide bottom div Upwards when Div above dissapears

Tags: jquery

I've been messing with the fadein fadeout functions in jquery and would like to know if it's possible that the div below slides upwards instead of jumping up as soon as the div above it disappears. Here's a little jsfiddle I did :)

http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/2j5FU/1/

Thanks again :)

Thanks to everyone that helped me out, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slideDown` and `slideUp` instead of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` respectively.

http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/H87pc/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :)) Thanks FishBasketGordo :))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `.slideUp()` instead of `.fadeOut()`

**edit:**

if you insist of fading out you could do it like this:

```
$(element).animate({opacity: 0, duration: 200}, function(){
    $(this).slideUp(100);
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j5FU/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried slideUp() and slideDown() instead of fadeIn and fadeOut? That should provide the effect your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try using `animate`

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
    case 'button1':
        $('#div1').fadeIn(200);
            $("#div1").animate({opacity: 1}, 2000,function(){
            $(this).slideDown();
            });
        break;
    case 'button2':
             $("#div1").animate({opacity: 0}, 2000,function(){
             $(this).slideUp();
            });
        break;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2j5FU/5/